# Ninja doesn't use CC and CXX?

Tags: gcc, clang, ninja

I'm compiling Tesseract with Ninja. Clang has some linking problem, but gcc works. I exports CC and CXX with gcc and `make -j8` runs fine. However, Ninja (using the given script in `/build` folder) still uses clang. How can I specify compiler in Ninja, using a *given* `.ninja` script?

Comment: Judging from the [Ninja manual](https://ninja-build.org/manual.html), you'd have to look at the Ninja file and deduce what to change — it is not like `make` and does not seem to have default macros etc.  It describes itself as an 'assembler' for builds.  It expects some other tool to be used to generate its control file.  And how you change compilers depends on how the file is generated.  You can do it manually; you aren't expected to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Method1:

ninja is a very simplified and powerful build system. You only need to look at `build.ninja` and `rules.ninja` files to make relevant changes.

`build.ninja` contains build commands to be run in order to build the project.

`rules.ninja` contains rules, `CC`, `CXX` and other flags. In order to change the compiler for a  specific rule you'd need to `grep` for that target in `rules.ninja`. There might be several rules you'd like to change, in that case you can use some bash magic.

### Method2

All said, changing `*.ninja` files is not recommended as they are generated by cmake. So you should modify the compiler paths (`CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER`, `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` flags) in `CMakeCache.txt` file in your build directory.

### Method3

Remove the build directory completely, then export `CC` and `CXX` flags or pass the `-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/path/to/c++compiler -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/path/to/c-compiler` while invoking cmake. e.g.,

```
cmake -GNinja \
-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/path/to/c++compiler \
-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/path/to/c-compiler \
... <other-flags>
<path-to-llvm-repo>
```

I'd recommend Method3, YMMV. hth.

Comment: I already use method 3. Just want to ask for a way to NOT rewriting the `ninja` file though.

Comment: Where is rules.ninja located?

Comment: the rules.ninja file is created in the folder where `cmake` was run. you can also use the `find` command to find rules.ninja file.